# Mysterious type assertion failure?

Tags: reflection, types, go

Under what circumstances could this code:

```
        v, ok := value.(int64)
        if !ok  {
            panic("NOPE "+reflect.TypeOf(value).Kind().String())
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("VAL: %d\n",v)
        }
```

produce the panic with message `panic: NOPE int64`?

Is this a bug or is there something basic about the numeric types that I'm missing?

Comment: If it helps, the value was an `int64` passed through an `interface{}` function parameter into the function that this code is in. (It's a long function, and simple attempts to reproduce this elsewhere have failed...)

Comment: I ran your code and it runs perfectly well. the problem is outside this snippet. see http://play.golang.org/p/NCHCVqz13C

Comment: As I said, I cannot create a MCVE - it's just failing /in situ/, and of course works by itself (or we'd be in real trouble!).   If you prefer, "what possible problems outside of this snippet could cause this?"   - I don't see any way at all that the behavior I'm describing can happen legally, regardless of what I've "messed up" elsewhere... but my understanding of "legally" may be incorrect.

Comment: oh, I can easily recreate it by doing something like `type T int64` and making `value` reference a `T`.  what does just printing `reflect.TypeOf(value)` give you?

Comment: Ah.   I think you hit it.   So, I can have types with typekind Int64 that are not int64?   That is actually exactly what I'm doing, I think.   Do I need the reflect Convert() to convert them (via the "unknown" type) back to "proper" int64?  Or what?

Comment: well then, that settles it. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can happen if you're using type declaration on numeric types. If you do something like this:

```
type T int64 

...

var value interface{} = T(1)
```

and put it into your code, you'll get the exact same error. But if you don't check the kind, but the type, you'll see what's happening here:

```
v, ok := value.(int64)
if !ok {
    panic("NOPE " + reflect.TypeOf(value).String())
} else {
    fmt.Printf("VAL: %d\n", v)
}
```

produces the message:

```
panic: NOPE main.T
```

The `kind` of T is  int64, but `value` is *not* int64.

Comment: Fantastic, TYVM.    But, how can I convert that back to an int64 without "knowing" the (compile-time symbol) type in question?   Hm, that should be a followup question probably...  will post.

Comment: @BadZen You can do that with reflect: `var i int64 = reflect.ValueOf(value).Int()`

Comment: I have a giant switch with int64, int32, int16... and so forth.   `<intType>(reflect.Value.Int())` with a static conversion works great as does using reflect.Type.Convert(targetType).   Thanks again!

Comment: Well, ok, careful, me.  "works" up to int/uint funniness.   There's a reflect.Value.Uint(), too, though.  Convert() does the right thing without thinking about it.   Either way tho.

Comment: so is your switch on the kind? then you can have multiple values per case. e.g. `case int, int16, int32, int64` - Value.Int() will work on all of them the same.

Comment: Yup.   Was just noting that I need to split out the `uint` and friends cases  and use `Value.Uint()` there or else potentially probably chop a bit.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer "type aliasing": the only aliased types in Go are the built in `byte` and `rune` types (aliases of `int8` and `int32`). Anything done via a [type declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations) creates a new type with it's own [identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity), not an alias of anything.

Comment: @DaveC I was too lazy looking in the docs for the right term, but I hoped you might correct me, so thanks :) I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @DaveC - Nitpick on that for posterity:  it seeems it's `uint8` and `int32` respectively.  (Any insight into why signed unicode codepoints?)   http://play.golang.org/p/46dCU9duck

Comment: @BadZen, you're right I made a mistake/typo and a byte is uint8. I don't know why `rune` is signed since the negative values are invalid code points. It may be because either signed or unsigned, having any of the top ~dozen bits set is an invalid code point and signed is somehow easier/safer (whereas for a byte there isn't any choice).